# Statistics on Hiring and Separations in European countries?

Tags: data-request, euro-area, labour, labour-economics, data-sources

I am looking for statistics on Hiring and Separations in European countries. That is, data similar to what is produced :

- monthly by BLS in the [JOLTS](https://www.bls.gov/news.release/jolts.nr0.htm) in the US.
- quarterly by Dares in France (quarterly statistics can be found [here](https://dares.travail-emploi.gouv.fr/dossier/les-mouvements-de-main-doeuvre-des-salaries-du-prive) in French ; micro data are [here](https://www.casd.eu/en/source/labour-movements/)).

Are you aware of similar monthly/quarterly statistical releases on hiring and/or separations in other European countries ?

Thank you in advance,